# ¿Se puede cambiar el formato de la semana del mat-date-picker?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

Estoy intentando colocar los días de la semana en el mat-datepicker en el formato de la semana que usamos en España (De Lunes a Domingo) porque originalmente, el mat-datepicker viene en el formato americano (De Domingo a Sábado)...

Este es el formato original del calendario que quiero cambiar:

[image: Esta es la imagen]

Este es mi html:

```
<td style="align-items: center;" class="ui-resizable-column">
   <input 
     matInput
     [matDatepicker]="picker"
     [formControl]="setDefault(p.comienzo)"
     (dateChange)="SetFechas( p.id, $event )"
     style="text-align: center; width: 61% !important;max-width: 70px !important;
     margin-bottom: 0px; border: 0px; background: none;">
   
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matPrefix [for]="picker">
      <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>calendar_month</mat-icon>
   </mat-datepicker-toggle>

   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</td>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección rpaillao!

Comment: Ya te salen los días de la semana en español, ¿qué hiciste para que se vean así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes modificar el `locale` de los componentes de Angular Material de manera estática así:

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'es-ES'},
  ],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

Pero también puedes permitir cambios dinámicos usando el API de DateAdapter:

```js
export class DatepickerLocaleExample {
  constructor(
    private adapter: DateAdapter<any>,
    @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) private locale: string,
  ) {}

  spanish() {
    this.locale = 'es-ES';
    this.adapter.setLocale(this._locale);
  }
  ...
}
```

He creado un ejemplo, basado en el que genera [la documentación oficial](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyfhe4?file=src/app/datepicker-locale-example.ts

Como puedes ver, se cambia el orden de los días de la semana, así como el nombre de los días y los meses.